# Some general information about assembly

Tags: assembly, cpu, low-level

I accidentally ended up here: http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/09/a-low-level-curriculum-for-c-and-c/, and it turned out to be one of the most informative collection of stuff I have read so far. I knew that assembly was some kind of a low level language that can be executed directly by a processor, but, I also read that each processor has it's own assembly.

**Questions:**

- Is this true?
- Will I be able to run some basic assembly on both my netbook and my PC?
- Is the only difference between, say, AVRs (who use the RISC architecture) and x86 processors who use the CISC, the instruction set they use?
- How do you run assembly code and in what kind of files do you store it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "normal processor". Maybe you mean x86, which is by far the most common one *on desktop systems*?

Comment: Assembly=the language. Assembler=the compiler.

Comment: @delnan, yes, that's what I meant. I edited the question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, to an extend. Although two processors from the same family might have different assembly languages, in reality one language may be an *extension* of the other. Sometimes processors from different manufacturers (e.g. Intel and AMD) share a great deal of their instruction set. Moreover, in spite of the vast number of assembly languages out there, they all share a relatively small number of fundamental concepts. Once you learn to program in one assembly language, learning a second one is usually an order of magnitude easier undertaking. Of course there are exceptions to this rule: for example, learning an assembly for a CPU that follows Harvard architecture is slightly trickier than learning your second Von Neumann assembly. Switching between RISC and CISC may present challenges as well.
2. It depends: if your PC and your netbook have CPUs from the same family, you may get lucky. There's more than the instruction set to being able to run an assembly language program, though: the operating system matters a lot, too. For example, Linux and Windows do not share the same format of executable files.
3. There is a lot more to hardware than the instruction set. There are CPUs with identical instruction sets that use very different hardware. The classic example is 8088 vs. 8086: their instruction sets are identical, but their hardware differs rather fundamentally because of the width of their external data bus.
4. You run assembly code by first compiling it, the same way you do your C programs. `.asm` is a typical extension for your assembly programs, but it's far from being a universal rule. You can also embed assembly into your C/C++ files using compiler-specific extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Each processor *architecture* has its own assembly language, meaning its own set of instructions. Most instruction sets are reasonably similar, so by learning any one of them you have at least a chance of figuring out waht is going on on another architecture. If both your netbook and PC are some kind of *86, they are probably almost identical.

The easiest way to experiment with assembly is to embed a little bit of assembly code in a C program. This is called "inline assembly" (you can find some examples with a google search). This allows you to have the C program do the high-level stuff like input and output, and have the assembly just do some calculations with that data.

Answer (score 2):

Each processor family has its own instruction set.

There are some assemblers that can translate input from two (or more) different instruction sets -- for a few examples, Google "table driven assembler". These usually use similar syntax across all the processors they work with, which may be (often is) anywhere from slightly to drastically different from the assembler that's "native" to that processor (e.g., the one provided by the processor vendor).

As that suggests, there are also processors with two (or more) different assemblers in wide use, sometimes using completely different syntax. Just for an obvious example, on x86 processors, both Intel syntax and AT&T syntax are in common use.

From a programming viewpoint, the processor's instruction set and available registers are pretty much all that's visible of that processor. Both of those vary (radically) between processors.

Code written in assembly language is normally stored in a source file. The extension varies with the assembler (e.g., ".asm" or ".S"). You assemble that much like you would compile code written in an higher level language. That produces an object file. From there you link to produce an executable, just about like any other object file.